# Strategy for onAuthStateChanged usage on SPA

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, single-page-application

I have some doubts and questions regarding the `onAuthStateChanged` used as an observable in a SPA type webapp... do I created once in the init phase of Firebase Auth or do I need to use in in every components that I want verify user authentication status?

Comment: I think it depends on the type of SPA you are using. I think you can use either (on init as long as you can notify your other components later if auth changes occur, or you can subscribe a new observer for each component and unsubscribe when the component is destroyed).

Comment: Didn't think about unsubscribe the observers during component been destroyed, sounds good!